# Migrate a qcow2 image between storage pools

Tags: kvm, virtualization, qemu, libvirt

I have 2 storage pools.

1. host_images (directory storage pool)
2. remote_images (nfs storage pool)

How do I copy qcow images from remote_images to host_images using libvirt APIs?

I've tried using the obvious vol-clone, but apparently it doesn't work across storage pools

I've tried using vol-download but that takes an obscene amount of time (in the order of 10+mins for 500MB)

Am I architecting this wrong? 
Should I not be trying to use libvirt to control these aspects of automation?

I wanted to use libvirt for all aspects of automation so I could be consistent in my tool utilization. But if the tools don't work I cannot continue to use libvirt.

I'm also wondering if vol-clone does not work how does KVM perform migration to another host? What tools does it use to migrate if not libvirt?

Answer (score 3):

`virt-clone` worked for me:

> virt-clone --original vm-name --name vm-name-clone --file /path/to/new/pool/name.img